# Getting error in my vscode setting for C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I My VScode was working before an update. Now whenever I run VSCode to compile and run I get the following error:

```
cd "c:\Users\luckv\Google Drive\CS41\Assignment\Binary Tree Lab 3.0\" && g++ main.cpp -o main && "c:\Users\luckv\Google Drive\CS41\Assignment\Binary Tree Lab 3.0\"main
bash: cd: too many arguments
```

I am a noobie, I suspect its something in my config files. Directions would be appreciated. Yes I am running a C++

Comment: Although this may not be the issue in c++ its best to never ever use a path that contains a space. Most compilers are command line utilities and a space on the command line means a different argument. Yes quoting gets around this however even that can fail causing you pain.

Comment: thanks, I'll keep that in mind when I create new projects. It's new habits I'll have to adapt :-) But yes, even projects without that space the error still exist.

Comment: Which shell do you use? This looks like Windows. Does Windows support `&&`?

Comment: yes this is vscode on windows.

Comment: I recommend to change the IDE. Visual Studio Code is a very powerful and great IDE but it's not beginner friendly. I recommend Visual Studio, CLion, Cevelop or Eclipse CDT. It will work out of the box.

Comment: under code its listed as bash. not sure if windows support &&. How would I edit it. Thanks for your patience

Comment: Windows does support `&&` on the command line. I use it with batch files all the time.

Comment: @ThomasSablik true I am also using in ubuntu environment right now but only playing around. Plus I want to understand why my setup is messed up and try to understand how to fix it. Switching to VS or CLion is probably a good idea for now, but in the back of my head I am still trying to figure where I went wrong. Maybe I should just nuke the setup and start from scratch?

Comment: @ThomasSablik can you give me directions how to edit it? Thanks for you patience. I suspect with an update it broke something because before it was fine. But the problem was I was following a tutorial that didn't really explain what I was doing but it did work.

Comment: I think you don't need the `cd` part. AFAIK you can set the current working directory, compile the code and run the program. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp and https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks

Comment: when I try to run the command without cd I get this error $ bash: too many arguments
bash: bash:: command not found

Comment: Your configuration is broken. I gave you two links with documentation. There you can find `options` and `cwd`. The latter is the option for current working directory. Do you know JSON? The configuration is in JSON format.

Comment: Yes thank you. I'll read your link. I know how to get into JSON. I'll get to this post after I play around with and try some things out. Thank you everyone for your patience and suggestion

Comment: `tasks.json` is the file that compiles. `launch.json` is used for debugging.